# when i run the java code in vscode nothing happen put it

Tags: java

this is the code :

```
public class joky {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("joky");
    }
}
```

i expecting from the compiler to print "joky"
I commented on this problem for days, I watched videos on YouTube, but I could not solve the problem, and I downloaded jdk, and I am sure that storing the java file in the main memory of the device

Comment: Do it from the command line. If it works from the command line, then it's a VS Code issue and you need to check out those forums for help. If it doesn't work from the command line, then it's a JDK/JRE issue and you need to debug your Java installation.

Comment: "i expecting from the compiler to print "joky"" Technically the compiler doesn't run the program. Are you using javac to create `joky.class`? You can run the program with java.

Answer (score 0):

`Install Langauge Suppport` for Java and `Debugger for Java` Extensions and then Run->Debug.

Comment: Tried it on my VS.Code installation, after starting to edit a Java program, it offered to install the "Extension Pack for Java"; after doing so, it offers a "Run" button directly in the source code (after the "class" line in the source code) which works as expected, and also a "Debug" button.